# How to fetch json.gz in a modern browser without third-party libraries?

Tags: javascript, json, frontend, backend, gzip

json.gz file is a compressed json, like: {"abc":1}
How to make the browser understand that this is compressed json and unpack it itself to a JS object?

I found this option, but it didn't work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/41925.json.gz?callback=parseResponse"></script>
```

`The script from “http://localhost:8080/41925.json.gz?callback=parseResponse” was loaded even though its MIME type (“application/gzip”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.`

I can set different headers in the backend, but I don't know which ones.

Comment: Browsers don't automagically turn JSON into objects. You'll need to write a script that [`fetches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the data from your endpoint, and then parse it.

Comment: JSONP is `application/javascript`,  but I'd strongly suggest you avoid using `JSONP` for security reasons..   Also the `gz` part is usually something you don't need to worry about, the browser and backend should be sorting this out.

Comment: @Andy  Looks like he's trying to use JSONP, yeah, I know, JSON and proper CORS settings would be better.

Comment: Why pre-compress the file? You should be able to configure your server to compress the files transparently for you. Might need some extra headers on the request but the browser will then handle the expansion for you behind the scenes. https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: Resource files can be automatically compressed/decompressed as Nick commented.  Yet, why are you doing JSONP on a server and resource that you control?  Please provide more detail, i.e., what is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Yogi  `as Nick commented`,  I often think my comments are invisible.. :)

Comment: I made a local web server that gives a lot of compressed json files. Security in the local environment is not important, nothing is encrypted and there is no Internet and I am the single owner of this. Json files are large and rarely updated and are stored compressed in a folder on disk.

Comment: I wrote 2 headers [Content-Encoding: gzip , Content-Type: application/json] and it worked for fetch. But it doesn't work for script/callback.

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried. What http server are you using? If you've not changed any settings it may be compressing your compressed file

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 headers [Content-Encoding: gzip , Content-Type: application/json] and it worked for fetch.